# Create User in firebase - Realtime Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stuck with creating a Firebase User.

After creating my database looks like this

[image]

I created a struct User but I don't know how to create the correct dictionary

```
struct User {
let email : String
let name : String
let lastname : String
let phone : String
let password : String
let uid: String
let car : [Car]

init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any] ) {
    self.uid = uid
    
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.lastname = dictionary["lastname"] as? String ?? ""
    self.phone = dictionary["phone"] as? String ?? ""
    self.password = dictionary["password"] as? String ?? ""
    self.car = dictionary["car"] as? String ?? "" <- this is wrong
}


struct Car {
let firstCar : [FirstCar]}
struct FirstCar {
let brandName : String
let capacity : String
let carName : String
let fueal : String
let model : String
let power : String
let year : String}
```

help

Comment: Is there a question here? What's wrong with your code and structure, and what are you trying to do? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: Also the `namename` field will not be populated because its `lastName` in firebase (capital N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about how to populate the User object from the Realtime Database when there's a child node involved that is also a key: value pair.

My suggestion is to keep Firebase 'firebasey' as long as possible by using DataSnapshots and not cast to dictionaries; it makes getting data from child nodes much easier and cleaner.

Here's and example of reading a users node from Firebase

```
var userArray = [UserClass]()

func readAllUsers() {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users") //self.ref points to my firebase
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let user = UserClass(userSnap: child)
            self.userArray.append(user)
        }
    })
}
```

and then the UserClass with a child key: value pair with a car brand as a child

```
class UserClass {
    var key = ""
    var userName = ""
    var userEmail = ""
    var type = ""
    var brand = ""
    
    convenience init(userSnap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.key = userSnap.key
        self.userName = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
        self.userEmail = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as? String ?? "No email"

        let carSnap = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "car") //retuns the car node
        let firstCarSnap = carSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "firstCar") //return the firstCar node
        self.brand = firstCarSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "brandName").value as? String ?? "No Brand"
    }
}
```

It's a good idea to store users by their uid and also keep track of that in the object in case you need to reference that user or update their node elsewhere in your code.

Note this line in the above code

```
for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
```

preserves the ordering of the users when they are read in.