# Parse data JSON from Firebase Swift with Node

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in Firebase as shown in the photo.
But I can't get the json format. Everything only works if I enter the node name in the model as below.

Working model for json (`LNiTKMpNKHYVqTwyyY52k36Aqvo1` is entered only to show the working example)

```
struct SearchedUser: Decodable {
    let LNiTKMpNKHYVqTwyyY52k36Aqvo1: SearchedPerson
}

struct SearchedPerson: Decodable {
    let uid: String
    var username: String
    var name: String
    var bio: String
    var avatarUrl: String
    let avatarBackgroundHex: String
}
```

[image: Firebase struct]

Comment: What does it mean "I can't get"? What error do you get, what code do you use to decode the json?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, in the SearchedUser structure, I specified a uid that is automatically generated, but I don't really know what the uid is, if in this structure I replace 'LNiTKMpNKHYVqTwyyY52k36Aqvo1' with 'uid', I will get the following error 'error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "UIR", certificate from its encoded form: zero), quickly.Decoding error.Context (codingPath: [], debugDescription: "no value associated with the CodingKeys key (stringValue: \"uid\", intValue: nil) (\"uid\").", underlyingError: nil))'

Comment: So you probably have a dictionary then, try replacing SearchedUser with `[String: SearchedPerson]` and then access the values of the dictionary

Comment: Thanks for helping here @JoakimDanielson. Do you want to post that as an answer, so we can upvote it and bring closure to this question?

Comment: There are probably better ways to go about this but we would need to see what your code that reads users looks like to make a suggestion. Take a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67027962/create-user-in-firebase-realtime-database/67045347#67045347) which may help and doesn't need decodable.